# Use Subclass of UITableView in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using [STCollapseTableView](https://github.com/iSofTom/STCollapseTableView) for expand/collapse tableView cells.
I've integrated it through cocoapods and imported it in Bridging-Header.
In my VC:

```
class MyVC: UITableViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView = STCollapseTableView()
  }

}
```

I have assigned the `tableView` to be `STCollapsableTableView`.
I am getting two issues:

1. `self.tableView` is of type `UITableView` and not of `STCollapsableTableView`.
2. I am not able to call the functions defined in `STCollapsableTableView` like `- (void)openSection:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex animated:(BOOL)animated;`
   I think that I have to subclass my current VC to be able to use these, but I am really not sure on how to do it.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094158/overriding-superclass-property-with-different-type-in-swift) question, but it doesn't help me. I want to override `UITableView` with `STCollapseTableView` in `MyVC` and use all the methods defined in it. Also, `MyVC` has to be a subclass of `UITableViewController` because of structural dependency. Please suggest a way to achieve it.

I am using Swift 2.3

Comment: I would not subclass UITableView, rather create a data source class that implements UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate and knows about collapsing and other tasks.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I am trying to reuse a gitHub library.

Comment: just because it is on github doesn't mean it is a good approach.

Comment: @vikingosegundo agreed, but its still a quick and dirty solution. But thanks for the suggestion, I will try doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a computed property in MyVC:

```
private var collapseTableView: STCollapseTableView {
    return tableView as! STCollapseTableView
}
```

You can also store it if you access it often, to avoid many casts.
The rest is OK :)

Comment: I am getting the following error: `Could not cast value of type 'UITableView'  to 'STCollapseTableView'`

Comment: Can you check if `STCollapseTableView` is a subclass of `UITableView`? It shouldn't give you this error, especially since you can do `self.tableView = STCollapseTableView()`.

Comment: Yes it is a subclass of `UITableView`

Comment: I just did the same thing and it worked, so there must be something different on your side.
You're getting this error at compile time, right? On which line? Also, does `self.tableView = STCollapseTableView()` work properly?

Comment: Its fine when I just declare it as above. But it crashes once I try to do this: `collapseTableView.openSection(sectionToExpand, animated: true)` with the error `Could not cast value of type 'UITableView' to 'STCollapseTableView'`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call `openSection` before setting `tableView` to an instance of `STCollapseTableView`. Place breakpoints on `self.tableView = STCollapseTableView()` and on `collapseTableView.openSection(sectionToExpand, animated: true)` to see where it stops first.

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard go to your ***tableViewController*** click on ***tableView*** of your ***tableViewController*** go to ***Identity Inspector*** and enter ***STCollapseTableView*** in the ***class*** field.

After this you should be good.

Comment: I am not using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to override the loadView method. Check out the swift example given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32107450/2741745